# DataTables warning: table id=tbl - Invalid JSON response. about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

Tags: php, json, ajax, datatable

i made an html file and j query inside data table and ajax to call the data from PHP file

Comment: Really hard for us to tell where it goes wrong without seeing the PHP code. Check the response, its probably an error somewhere.

Comment: <?php
    $server = "127.0.0.1";
    $db = "company";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "";
    try {
        $con = new PDO("mysql: host=$server; dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
        $stmt =$con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "connection failed ".$e->getMessage();
    }
?>

Comment: when i open the php file in local  they represent the array doneArray ( [0] => Array ( [donor_Id] => 1 [fname] => mhmadmhmad [bloodg] => B+ [gender] => F [email] => mohamadsmeit@gmail.com [phone] => 81263673 [city] => Jafarabad [Medical] => no disease )  )

Comment: If you want us to help you, try to show us a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table=$('#tbl').dataTable({
        "serverSide":true,
        "ajax": {
            url: "search.php",
            dataSrc: ""
        },
        columns:[ {
            data: "donor_Id"

```
    },    {
            data: "fname"

        },
        {
            data: "bloodg"

        },
        {
            data: "gender"
        },{
            data: "email"

        }

    ]});
```

});